# Sending binary data over IPC from C to Python

Tags: python, c, sockets, serialization

I have a C program and a Python program on the same machine.  The C program generates some data in nested structures. What form of IPC is the best way to get this data across to the python program?

Serializing in C (especially nested structures) is a real bear, from what I hear, due to lack of serialization libraries.  I am not very familiar with shared memory, but I assume the formatting of the C structures may not be very palatable to the python program when it comes to memory alignment and following pointers.  The ctype and struct library seems to be for non-nested structures only.  So far, what I am thinking is:

Wrap all the data in the C program into some xml or json format, write it via socket to python program and then let python program interpret the xml/json formatted data.  Looks very cumbersome with lots of overheads.

Any better ideas ?

Comment: You could have a look on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001827/os-independent-inter-program-communication-between-python-and-c

Answer (score 2):

I think you answered your own question. JSON is certainly a good choice. It's also not terribly difficult to do your own serialization in C.